# VBA select count from field where and clause

Tags: excel, ms-access, excel-2007, vba

This appears to be something simple but i'm getting an error when i execute the below vba statement:

```
Dim currentmth As String
currentmth = Sheets("Data").Range("f3") ----this stores the month name
strSql = "SELECT count(Emails_Submitted) As Total FROM tablename WHERE Emails_Submitted > 1 '" & tc_mth = currentmth & "'"

cn.Open strConnection
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)
countfrmdb = rs.Fields(0)
cellref = countfrmdb
```

Error message: Invalid sql statement

Comment: The syntax is bad. Change `> 1 '" & tc_mth = currentmth & "'"` to `>1 AND tc_mth = '" & currentmth & "'"`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I think what you provided now works but i'm getting another error "data type mismatch in expression". I'm guessing this is due to the fact that the column i'm counting contains numbers stored as text. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: make sure the datatype for the currentmth variables matches the datatype for the tc_mth field.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks a ton, it works perfectly now!!